# Jenkins Buildserver remove prefix with wildcard

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

In the last time I try to use Jenkins to build my Maven artifacts.

I have a Maven project called *Imladria*. It has some modules like *ImladriaCore*, *ImladriaLibrary* and *ImladriaDatabase* (examples, there are some more).

I have a Maven project in my Jenkins build server. Jenkins fetches all sources from my Gitlab server and builds all artifacts. After building it will publish all artifacts over FTP on my server.

It publishes them with their whole prefix so i'll have this structure on my server:

```
/home/user/TestServer/ImladriaCore/target/...
/home/user/TestServer/ImladriaLibrary/target/...
/home/user/TestServer/ImladriaDatabase/target/...
```

And so on.

I want my Jenkins to publish all built `.jar` in the same directory. I know that I have to remove the prefix. But this would only work without the *ImladriaCore*, *Library*, ... files when they are in they target direcory. E.g.:

```
/home/user/TestServer/target/ImladriaCore-1.0-Snapshot.jar
/home/user/TestServer/target/ImladriaLibrary-1.0-Snapshot.jar
/home/user/TestServer/target/ImladriaDatabase-1.0-Snapshot.jar
```

I tried many permutations of removing `**/target/` `*/target/` or whatever as a prefix to publish all `.jar` in the same directory (`/home/user/TestServer/`).

I always get this error:

```
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message
[Failed to remove prefix from file named [ImladriaCore/target/imladriacore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar].
Prefix [*/target/] must be present in all file paths]
```

Does anyone know which wildcard I would have to choose?

My configuration of publishing:

- [Publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYUMX.png)
- [Server config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27uOP.png)

Thank you and Regards
- Felix